# Error in subset object not found (with geom_point in ggplot2)

Tags: r, object, dataframe, ggplot2, subset

I'm trying to get my head around this:

I've got the below data.frame:

```
df<-data.frame(read.csv(file="C:/Users/136728/Desktop/R/TestIRIC.csv",
header=TRUE))
```

And I try to plot the below graph with ggplot2 using subset:

```
ggplot(data = df) + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(data = subset(subset(data = df, y > 0 & y < 100), x > 250 & x < 375), aes(x = x, y = y), colour = "pink")
```

The idea is to reproduce the below graph:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBBHF.png)

However I get the below error message: "Error in subset(data = df, y > 0 & y < 100) : object 'y' not found".
Please note that another code below using subset and the same df works perfectly fine:

```
ggplot(data = df) + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(data = subset(df, Group == "Group1"), aes(x = x, y = y), colour = "pink")
```

Your help would be really appreciated!

Comment: It's `subset(x = df, y > 0 & y < 100)`. `subset` doesn't take a `data` parameter.

Comment: Ok then I've fot the below code to do the y highlight:                    ggplot(data = df) + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(data = subset(x = df, y > 0 & y < 100), aes(x = x, y = y), colour = "pink")                             but I how I combine the x & y highlight? I want x to be = x > 250 & x < 375                               Thanks again!

Comment: try using data=df[df$y>0&df$y<100&df$x>250&df$x<375,]

Comment: Indeed I feel like I should specify that x and y belong to df, however the above doesn't work...

Comment: Next time share a reproducible example, something like `dput(head(df))`, and we'll see your data and be able to test possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will do what you want, I think. Here the points are colored by the boolean value that indicates whether they fall within the range or not. Then `scale_color_manual` is used to manually define the colors of the two options. In general, I think it is better to use the color parameter to correctly color the points, rather than plotting a second set on top of the first.

```
ggplot(data = df) + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, color = y > 0 & y < 100 & x > 250 & x < 375))+scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "pink"))
```

An alternative, and possibly more robust method, would be to first add a column to the `data.frame` indicating whether or not it fits the data i.e.:

```
df$in_range <- df$y>0&df$y<100&df$x>250&df$x<375
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = in_range)) + geom_point() + ...
```